# Example of a field $F$ and a structure $(V,+,s)$ satisfying all but one of the vector space axioms.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to find an example (if there exists one) of a field $F$ and a structure $(V,+,s)$ (where $s$ stands for scalar multiplication)   satisfying all but one of the axioms of a vector space, namely the distributivity  of vector addition: For all $c ∈ F$ and $v,w ∈ V$ , $c(v + w) = cv + cw$

I believe such example exists, but I'm not sure where to start. An exercise I did before asked to show how the axiom follows from the other axioms if $F=\mathbb{Q}$. So I think perhaps using a different field like $\mathbb{R}$ (or anything similar) could be of use.

Could anyone give me some advice or
hint to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: "namely the distributivity of vector addition." - To be clear, is this the axiom you mean? ($a \in F; \vec v, \vec w \in V$; scalar multiplication denoted by $\cdot$): $$a \cdot (\vec v + \vec w) = a \cdot \vec v + a \cdot \vec w$$

Comment: I think so. I see none other.

Comment: Yes, that's the axiom

Comment: [This might answer the question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215781/example-of-algebraic-structure-that-is-non-distributive-for-both-distributive-la)

Comment: @ClementYung I don't think so: that's looking for examples that fail distributive laws on both sides.  Here it's only one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael indeed you are right, but I'll be leaving the link as it might be a good motivation for a counterexample.

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412899/is-every-axiom-in-the-definition-of-a-vector-space-necessary will do.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/479005/589

Comment: Have you followed up on any of the comments, Andres?

Comment: Well, in the article "Independent Axioms of vector spaces" mentioned in the link given by Ihf, the author evaluates each axiom, including the one in question. Even if he proves that this axiom can be deduced from the other ones if F are rational numbers or a field of prime order, he states that if this is not the case, "Using rather deep properties of field extensions we can show counterexamples".  I'll put hte link here [link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615171?seq=1).