# Does the distributive property apply to all hyperoperations higher than multiplication?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, tetration, hyperoperation

Suppose we have a function defined like so;

$$f_n( x, x ) = f_{n+1}( x, 2 )$$

$$f_n( x, x, x ) = f_{n+1}( x, 3 )$$

$$f_n( x, x, x, x,\dots) = f_{n+1}( x, \text{number of} x\text{'s} )$$

$f_1( x, y ) = x + y$

We know that $f_2(f_1( x, y ), a ) = f_1( f_2( x, a ), f_2( y, a ) )$ because of the distributive property, but do all functions have this property?

Does $$f_{n+1}( f_n( x, y ),a ) = f_n( f_{n+1}( x, a ), f_{n+1}( y, a ) )$$ for any $n$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215781/example-of-algebraic-structure-that-is-non-distributive-for-both-distributive-la

Comment: No, I am inquiring about functions that are "repeated" forms of either addition, or other repeated functions (multiplaction, exponents, tetration, ect) The funciton used to answer this post mixes addition and multiplacation functions instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Let $f_1(x,y)=2x+3x+1$ so that $f_1(x,x)=5x+1$. Should $f_1(x,x,x)=5(5x+1)+1 =25x+6$? What is $f_2$ in this case?

Comment: @CyclotomicField - It is given that $f_1$ is addition.

Comment: @CalebThoburn - So $f_1(x,y)=x+y$, and $f_2(x,y)=x\cdot y$, and $f_3(x,y)=x^y$. But then what is $f_4(x,3)$, for example? You say it's $f_3(x,x,x)$, but does that mean $x^{(x^x)}$ or $(x^x)^x$? Exponentiation is not associative.

Comment: @mr_e_man f sub 4 is tetration, or repeated exponents f sub 4 (x,3) would be x^x^x, which is always read as(x^x)^x

Comment: [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) would be $x^{(x^x)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use infix notation for the hyperoperations:

$$a\times_0b=1+b$$
$$a\times_1b=a+b$$
$$a\times_2b=ab$$
$$a\times_3b=a^b$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad a\times_4b=a^{(a\times_4(b-1))},\quad a\times_41=a$$

We know that multiplication distributes over addition, on both sides. Exponentiation distributes over multiplication on the right but not on the left:

$$(x\cdot y)^a=(x^a)\cdot(y^a)$$
$$\qquad\qquad a^{(x\cdot y)}\neq(a^x)\cdot(a^y)=a^{(x+y)}$$

And addition distributes over succession:

$$(x\times_0y)\times_1a=(1+y)+a$$
$$(x\times_1a)\times_0(y\times_1a)=1+(y+a)$$
$$a\times_1(x\times_0y)=a+(1+y)$$
$$(a\times_1x)\times_0(a\times_1y)=1+(a+y)$$

What about tetration?

$$(x^y)\times_4a\overset?=(x\times_4a)^{(y\times_4a)}$$
$$a\times_4(x^y)\overset?=(a\times_4x)^{(a\times_4y)}$$

It's not right-distributive, as we can see with $a=2,x=2,y=3$:

$$(2^3)\times_42\overset?=(2\times_42)^{(3\times_42)}$$
$$(2^3)^{(2^3)}\overset?=(2^2)^{(3^3)}$$
$$2^{(3\cdot2^3)}\overset?=2^{(2\cdot3^3)}$$
$$2^{24}\neq2^{54}$$

And it's not left-distributive either, as we can see with $a=2,x=1,y=1$:

$$2\times_4(1^1)\overset?=(2\times_41)^{(2\times_41)}$$
$$2\neq2^2=4$$

Comment: Note that we only used tetration in the form $x\times_42=x^x$, so it doesn't matter whether it associates right or left ($x\times_43=x^{(x^x)}$ or $(x^x)^x$). In either case it doesn't distribute.